# Docker SQL Server relative data-path

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have a `docker-compose.yml` having this lines.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  mssql:
    image: localhost/local_mssql_server:mssqlserver
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - sqlfolder1234:/var/opt/mssql
```

The Docker is starting up successfully and serving data.

But I seldom work with windows and I like to know where is the host-folder `sqlfolder1234`?

I tried the windows-explorer to search for that folder. Since an hour he not finished yet.

Where is that folder `sqlfolder1234` on my host system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This volume type is called `Named volume` Here is some description from the official document. [Short syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#short-syntax-3)

> In the absence of having named volumes with specified sources, Docker creates an anonymous volume for each task backing a service. Anonymous volumes do not persist after
> the associated containers are removed.

```
volumes:
  # Just specify a path and let the Engine create a volume
  - /var/lib/mysql

  # Specify an absolute path mapping
  - /opt/data:/var/lib/mysql

  # Path on the host, relative to the Compose file
  - ./cache:/tmp/cache

  # User-relative path
  - ~/configs:/etc/configs/:ro

  # Named volume
  - datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
```

If you want to keep persistent data in your host computer, I would use another volume way to do that. this sample provides *Path on the host, relative to the Compose file* that help us can see the volumn folder in the docker-compose file level.

```
volumes:
      - ./sqlfolder1234:/var/opt/mssql
```